# How to execute ruby code from html?

Tags: html, ruby

I have a ruby file namely sample.rb. I want to execute that from my form and, actually my ruby code when executed will write to a html file. So what i need to do is when i click on the button in the form it should execute the ruby code and then it has to open the html file that comes from execution in one of the frame in my form. Is it is possible? If possible! how to do?

What i have tried is

```
<?php
exec("./sample.rb")
?>
```

But what it does is. It simply took the url of the api that i have used in ruby code and it returns the json from that api.

Comment: Can't understand the question due to grammatical errors. Could you please rewrite your question?

Comment: I don't think there is an error. May be you don't understand what i have quoted?

Comment: Facepalm... _Grammatical_ errors, not code errors. Meaning, the English portion of the question is badly written.

Comment: Could you show the ruby code, please?

Answer (score 1):

May be you should use rails for that http://rubyonrails.org

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking `sample.rb` as an external command, just like any other shell script. Therefore you have to capture and process its *output* yourself.

You say that "it returns the JSON from the api". That's fine, you can extract the data you are interested in, e.g.:

```
<?php
  $json = exec("./sample.rb");
  $data = json_decode($json);
  $url = $data->url; # assuming there is an URL field
?>
```

Now you can for example output a link:

```
<a href="<?php echo $url ?>">click</a>
```

or generate some JavaScript:

```
<script>
  window.location.href="<?php echo $url ?>";
</script>
```

or redirect the user via a HTTP header:

```
<?php
  header("Location: $url");
?>
```